# Below Function in my Chrome Extension returns undefined instead of true/false

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await, promise

I've created below function to check duplicate object in my chrome extension project. But It is returning undefined. True or False is expected.

Can you please modify it into the correct code for my scenario?

```
function checkDuplicate(obj){
    chrome.storage.local.get("savedContent", (savedContent) => {
        savedContent.savedContent.forEach((item) => {
            if(item.link === obj.link) {
                console.log('duplicateFound', true);
                return true;
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
}
```